# Arrk! ARC error:'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to convert some Apple code (from `SquareCam` example) to ARC. I had the Apple code flagged to compile as non-ARC and it worked but I was getting crash errors passing images between the non-ARC context to an ARC context - so I'm trying to resolve that.

Anyway, I think I have got all the ARC stuff handled except for this line:

```
 NSNumber *orientation = CMGetAttachment(imageDataSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyOrientation, NULL);
```

This is used for the `CIDetectorImageOrientation` key value (CoreImage face detection). I get the ARC error below for this and none of the stuff I have tried resolves this. "imageDataSampleBuffer" is of type `CMSampleBufferRef`.

What is the correct way to convert the CFTypeRef to the NSNumber I need? - Thanks!

> Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'CFTypeRef' (aka
>   'const void *') to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with ARC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are assigning a CFTypeRef to an NSObject*, the compiler complains.  You need to do a `__bridge` to an NSNumber.

Comment: Thanks! I used `__bridge` since I don't want to transfer ownership and that seems to work. Usually the compiler squawks and offers `__bridge` options but it didn't with the issue I was having.

Comment: Absolutely!  Though, I worry about the retain count of the CF object... If it crashes, use CFRetain() on that CMGetAttachment.

Comment: `__bridge_transfer` is wrong. The get rule says that the object is not owned by the caller and so he cannot transfer ownership to ARC.

Comment: @CodaFi There's no ownership problem with using `(__bridge NSNumber*)`. Don't just drop `CFRetain` calls without knowing why.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if these important details were collected in a wiki rather than being somewhat orphaned in comments.