# Passing 'CFTypeRef _Nullable' (aka 'const void *') to parameter of type 'void * _Nullable' discards qualifiers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to get an old project to work with ARC in iOS 10.2 (the project began under iOS 4). In two places I get the following warning

```
    Passing 'CFTypeRef _Nullable' (aka 'const void *') to parameter of type 'void * _Nullable' discards qualifiers
```

The first happens in `setUpPlayQueue` at line `CFBridgingRetain(self),`.

```
- (void)setUpPlayQueue
{
    AudioQueueNewOutput(
        &audioFormat,
        playCallback,
        CFBridgingRetain(self), 
        NULL,                   // run loop
        kCFRunLoopCommonModes,  // run loop mode
        0,                      // flags
        &playQueue
        );

    self.gain = 1.0;
}
```

`setUpPlayQueue` is called from `setUpAudio`

```
- (void)setUpAudio
{
    if (playQueue == NULL)
    {
        [self setUpAudioSession];
        [self setUpPlayQueue];
        [self setUpPlayQueueBuffers];
    }
}
```

The second happens in `primePlayQueueBuffers` at line `playCallback(CFBridgingRetain(self), playQueue, playQueueBuffers[t]);`

```
- (void)primePlayQueueBuffers
{
    for (int t = 0; t < NUMBER_AUDIO_DATA_BUFFERS; ++t)
    {
        playCallback(CFBridgingRetain(self), playQueue, playQueueBuffers[t]);
    }
}
```

`primePlayQueueBuffers` is called from `start`

```
- (void)start
{
    if (!playing)
    {
        playing = YES;
        [self primePlayQueueBuffers];
        AudioQueueStart(playQueue, NULL);
    }
}
```

By setting the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for the build target (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/2348597)), I managed to disable ARC for `AudioBufferPlayer`(the file holding these methods) and get the project to build. Similar problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17038376/2348597) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439881/2348597) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16982856/2348597) offered no way to actually fix this problem.

Can anyone help please ? Thanks

**Update**

At the suggestion of Martin (and Amin), when I use `(__bridge void *)(self)` instead of `CFBridgingRetain(self)` - with the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag cleared - both warnings disappear. However when I build Xcode then reports

```
    Existing instance variable 'delegate' for property 'delegate' with assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained
```

Here is the delegate interface

```
@interface AudioBufferPlayer : NSObject <AVAudioSessionDelegate>

{
    id<AudioBufferPlayerDelegate> delegate;
    BOOL playing;
    Float32 gain;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;

    /// the audio queue object being used for playback
    AudioQueueRef playQueue;

    /// the audio queue buffers for the playback audio queue
    AudioQueueBufferRef playQueueBuffers[NUMBER_AUDIO_DATA_BUFFERS];

    /// the number of audio data packets to use in each audio queue buffer
    UInt32 packetsPerBuffer;

    /// the number of bytes to use in each audio queue buffer
    UInt32 bytesPerBuffer;
}

/*! 
 * The delegate that fills up the audio buffers. This is a weak reference; the 
 * delegate is not retained. 
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<AudioBufferPlayerDelegate> delegate;
```

In [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) it says

> Weak references are not supported in … iOS 4.

When I changed the property reference to `strong` and tried to build, Xcode initially reported several errors including one caused by a `dealloc` which I am reasonably certain Xcode had reinstated in the code (I know I had previously removed it). However after closing Xcode and reopening it, I am now able to build and run the project successfully with no errors or warnings.

Thanks Martin and Amin. Much appreciated.

Comment: Using `__bridge_retained()` didn't solve the problem?

Comment: IIRC it does not take away a qualifier. However, you pass an argument with pointer to const to a parameter without const. Since it is an object in your case, simply casting it should be harmless.

Comment: Amin, I can silence both warnings using `(__bridge id`) e.g. `(__bridge id)CFBridgingRetain(self),` and 
`playCallback((__bridge id)CFBridgingRetain(self), playQueue, playQueueBuffers[t]);`. But as soon as I clear the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag, Xcode reports “Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'id' to C pointer type 'void *' requires a bridged cast”

Comment: `(__bridge_retained void *)(self)` or `(__bridge void *)(self)` – depending on whether you want to retain self or not –  (as suggested by Amin) should work and compile without warnings.

Comment: Martin and Amin, I believe you put me on the right track. See my update.